# Loading multiple grammar files in SAPI 5.1

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi

I'm using an XML grammar file to develop a Command and Control application. Since there are around 4000 entries in the grammar I can't have it all in one file (it gives an error when I try to load it). I have written multiple XML grammar files, but when I try to load more than one file it replaces the previously loaded file. that is the program only recognizes the phrases in the second grammar file. Can anyone tell me how to load multiple grammars in a single speech recognition application?

Answer (score 3):

You can create multiple grammar, you have to give them different IDs.
These snippets are in Delphi, but you can adapt:

```
  // init
  FGrammar1 := SpSharedRecoContext1.CreateGrammar(1); // ID 1
  FGrammar1.CmdLoadFromFile('CommandMemo1.xml', SLODynamic);
  FGrammar2 := SpSharedRecoContext1.CreateGrammar(2); // ID 2
  FGrammar2.CmdLoadFromFile('CommandMemo2.xml', SLODynamic);
  // start
  FGrammar1.CmdSetRuleIdState(0, SGDSActive);
  FGrammar2.CmdSetRuleIdState(0, SGDSActive);
...
  // in the onRecognition event, test the grammar Id
  case Result.PhraseInfo.GrammarId of
    1: if SameText(Txt, 'erase memo') then
         Memo1.Text := ''
       else
       if SameText(Txt, 'select memo') then
         Memo1.SelectAll;  
    2: if SameText(Txt, 'copy memo') then
         CopyToClipboard(Memo1.Text)
       else
       if SameText(Txt, 'paste memo') then
         Memo1.Text := PasteFromClipboard;
    else
      raise Exception.Create('bad GrammarId');
  end;
```